# Ubuntu 18.04 filesystem filling up

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, disk-usage

My filesystem is filling up and i have no idea of what. I logged into the system and / was 100% full. After a restart space usage was down to normal again. After about half a day / is at 80% again. Here is the output of df -k:

```
df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1504112        0   1504112   0% /dev
tmpfs             307328     1960    305368   1% /run
/dev/sda2       51340768 38742300   9960800  80% /
tmpfs            1536624        8   1536616   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1536624        0   1536624   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         90368    90368         0 100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop1         88704    88704         0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop2          5120     5120         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
/dev/loop3         89984    89984         0 100% /snap/core/5742
tmpfs             307324       16    307308   1% /run/user/126
tmpfs             307324       48    307276   1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs             307324       32    307292   1% /run/user/1000
```

However, please have a look at Disk Usage analyzer:

[image]

According to this my fs only takes up 10GB. So i don't understand how it is possible, that / is at 80%. In my view, I have a phantom 20GB

I restarted the machine and here is the output of df -k:

```
 df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1504112       0   1504112   0% /dev
tmpfs             307328    1092    306236   1% /run
/dev/sda2       51340768 9912552  38790548  21% /
tmpfs            1536624       4   1536620   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1536624       0   1536624   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         89984   89984         0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop1         88704   88704         0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop2          5120    5120         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
/dev/loop3         90368   90368         0 100% /snap/core/5897
tmpfs             307324      12    307312   1% /run/user/126
tmpfs             307324       0    307324   0% /run/user/1001
```

Back to normal gain. Swap size is just 3GB. How is this possible?

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer. I run google-drive-ocamlfuse. This program mounts google drive as a fuse filesystem. It uses a directory for cache. The problem is, that when the cache is cleared, the space doesn't free up, becasue the files are open.

So when i dig down with du -hs, or with a gui tool, I don't see the space usage, becasue the files are not there anymore, but with df I can see the used space, and by the way, the space is used.
I was able to veryfy this with

```
sudo lsof | grep 'deleted'
```

There I can see all the opened and deleted files

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution but what you can do is run:

```bash
du -hs /* | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

Then traverse the biggest directory from the list by using first path from the list, i.e.:

```bash
du -hs /tmp/* | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

This way you'll find the dir that grows the most, I think.

My guess it's logs or any profiler you might be running, but you'll find out with this command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that if i do that, the overall fs consumption is 10G (please open the linked picture in the question). For that i used the gui tool Disk Usage Analyzer, but i also tried with 

    sudo du -sH /* 

and it told me the same thing as the gui, that I only use 10GB. So unfortunately the question still stands: How can disk usage be 40GB when / is only 10GB?

Comment: the df doesn't use most recent data (see: https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal) so that's not reliable way to measure it. please find the topmost directory and see which one creates so many files anyway. Your DF also shows the disk didn't change its size. something simply overtook a lot of space. the du command combination I suggested will pinpoint the folder and will allow you to check what is filling that particular folder by investigating more